# Putting array name in variable and shortening code

Tags: c#, array, beginner

I'm a beginner in C# and am doing a simple programming exercise. I would like to put the `Item.price` and `Item.Name` into `Listbox2`.

Is it possible to put the array name into a variable and iterate with a `foreach` loop?  This is to avoid a very long `if`, `switch`, or `while` loop.  It could also be useful in the future if I have 40 lists.

**Example**

```
Array variable = Drinks;
foreach(Product item in variable)
{
    listBox2.Items.Add(item.ProductName + item.Price);
}
```

PS: I've already tried using a temporary List, where I put the `Drinks` into the list and call it by `Product.Name` and/or `Product.price`.

Could it also be more efficient? I'm very open to new ideas or approaches on how I should make my code shorter and more efficient.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Product> Drinks = new List<Product>() { new Product("Coca Cola", 1.2F), new Product("Fanta", 2.0F), new Product("Sprite", 1.5F) };
        List<Product> Bread = new List<Product>() { new Product("Brown Bread", 1.2F), new Product("White Bread", 2.0F), new Product("Some otherBread", 1.5F) };
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
// instead of 40 if loops or a while loop is it possible to change the List Name with a variable and use only 1 foreach loop as the example i showed above?
            if (comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(comboBox1.SelectedItem) == 0)
            {
                foreach (Product item in Drinks)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(item.ProductName);
                }
            }
            else 
            {

                foreach (Product item in Bread)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(item.ProductName);
                }
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        private string productName;
        private float price;

        public Product(string productName, float price)
        {
            this.ProductName = productName;
            this.Price = price;
        }

        public string ProductName
        {
            get { return productName; }
            set { productName = value; }
        }

        public float Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set { price = value; }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to put the array name into a variable and iterate by a foreach loop?

**YES.**

```
Array ProductItems = Drinks.ToArray();
foreach(Product item in ProductItems)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.ProductName);
                    }
```

---

Now about your second question, (it's unclear what's the significance of the first question)...

If there are many products and user selects one from the `combobox1` how to update the product details in `listbox1`? (is this your question?)

**Answer** : Make a [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) of `combobox1` index and `ProductList`. Iterate over the `combobox1` list and map the indexes with the `ProductList`. [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695606/c-sharp-list-add-lists-to-dictionary).

```
Dictionary ProductDict = new Dictionary<int, List<Product>>();
```

Then after `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired get the `ProductList` corresponding with `combobox1` index. Then iterate over the list and add the details it in listbox.

---

**General Review**

Since `productName` and `price` is trivial make them [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

```
public string ProductName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Since both `Drinks` and `Bread` are `List<Product>`, there is no reason to use the non-generic `Array` here. Or to call `ToArray()`. (The fact that the original code does that is no excuse, I think code review should catch things like that too.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a variable that kan hold the reference to one of the lists, then you can loop through whatever that variable points to.

You can use a `switch` to select which of the lists you are referring to. Example:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  listBox1.Items.Clear();

  List<Product> products;
  switch (comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(comboBox1.SelectedItem)) {
    case 0: products = Drinks; break;
    case 1: products = Meat; break;
    case 2: products = Cheeses; break;
    case 3: products = Sauces; break;
    default: products = Bread; break;
  }

  foreach (Product item in products) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(item.ProductName);
  }

}
```

Comment: But OP states that he doesn't want a long switch-case statement which is true if there are like 100 items in the `combobox1` list.

Comment: @tintinmj: The OP has a switch with a loop for each case, which would be a very long switch with many cases, but assigning a reference in each case makes it a reasonably short switch even with many cases. It's not longer than populating a dictionary with the options for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new abstraction, instead of using a bunch of lists. For example:

```
class Category
{
     public string Name { get; private set; } //or other Id. Some Enum probably?

     public IList<Product> Products { get; private set; }

     public Category(string name)
     {
         Name = name;
         Products = new List<Products>();
     }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return Name;
     }
}
```

Then you can simply populate your `comboBox1` with `Category` objects, and handle selection event like this:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        var category = (Category)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        if (category == null) return;
        //cant you AddRange or assign? I'm not very familiar with winforms
        foreach (Product item in category.Products)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item.ProductName);
        }
    }
```

As for your first question: you can override `ToString` method of your `Product` class to return Name+Price the same way it is done for `Category`. Then you can simply call `listBox1.Items.Add(item);`